# Can't access virtual machine after plugging ethernet cable

Tags: ubuntu, networking, router, virtualbox, internet

I have VirtualBox installed. My OS is Ubuntu 13.10.
I configured a host only network at 192.168.56.1.
I have 2 machines the first 192.168.56.20 the other 192.168.56.21.

Everything worked fine before I plug my PC to a router so I can connect to the Internet.
The router IP address is 192.168.1.1 and my IP address in that network is 192.168.1.3.

My problem is when the cable is plugged in when I try to connect to 192.168.56.20 I get the local-host instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with virtualbox but you may need to look into bridged networking or some of the other networking modes available for the VM.

Comment: I don't want my network to be accessed from another network so I think I should use host only.Am I wrong? Maybe the problem is caused by the host system ?